# Ignore uppercase in a query, Python

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        if query == "song" or query == "songs":
            return render(request, 'music/cloud.html', {
                'songs': song_results,
                'generic_songs': song_results_generic,
            })
```

The thing is, I want the "if" statement to ignor uppercases.
For example, when the user search by "SoNg" or "SonG" or.. it will be converted to "song" before testing

Comment: Compare to `query.lower()`.

Comment: But when you are using lower() make sure that what you are comparing is also ".lower()" because python IS case sensitive.

Comment: the fact that this text comes from a `request.get` seems irrelevant here, it's just case insensitive string matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .lower()

```
if query.lower() in ['song', 'songs']:
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3.3+, you should prefer [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)
.

```
if query.casefold() in ['song'.casefold(), 'songs'.casefold()]:
```

From the docs:

> Return a casefolded copy of the string. Casefolded strings may be used for caseless matching.
>
> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example, the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to 'ß'; casefold() converts it to "ss".
>
> The casefolding algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.